Estimating Beta like integral
For $\alpha \in (0,1)$ define
$$p(x,z) =\frac{1}{(z-x) (z-1)^\alpha},\quad z>1,x \in (0,1),$$
I try to estimate the integral
$$ \int_1^\infty \left( \frac{z-1}{z} \right)^\gamma \frac{1}{(z-x) (z-1)^\alpha} d z$$
for $\gamma = \alpha$, I can factor out the $(z-1)^\alpha$ term and do the following
\begin{align}
&\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{z^\alpha (z-x)} dz \\
&=   x^{-\alpha} \int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{1}{t^{\alpha}(t-1)} d t\\
&= x^{-\alpha} \int_{0}^x \frac{y^{\alpha-1}}{1-y}  d y\\
&=  x^{-\alpha} \sum_{k=0}^\infty   \int_{0}^x y^k y^{\alpha-1} d y\\
&=  x^{-\alpha} \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{x^{\alpha +k}}{a+k}\\
&=  \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{x^{k}}{a+k}
\end{align}
The last term I can find upper and lower logarithmic bounds.
For $0<\gamma <\alpha$ I hope to get something similar but I am not sure what to do with the $(z-x)$ term.
I either get an unintegrable singularity or a $(1-x)^{-1}$ term.

The indefinite integral is an Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.

Mathematica gives a solution for the general case of the definite integral.

@ClaudeLeibovici could you please post it as an answer? I don't have access to wolfram mathematica

This is not an answer but just the result from Mathematica
$$I=\int_1^\infty \left( \frac{z-1}{z} \right)^\gamma \frac{dz}{(z-x) (z-1)^\alpha}$$
$$I=\pi  \csc (\pi  \alpha ) (-x)^{-\gamma} (1-x)^{\gamma -\alpha }-$$
$$\frac{\pi  \csc (\pi  \alpha ) \Gamma(\gamma-\alpha  +1)}{(1-x) \Gamma
   (2-\alpha ) \Gamma (\gamma )}\, _2F_1\left(1,\gamma-\alpha 
   +1;2-\alpha ;\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$$
